# python mySQLdb module not found issue in windows

Tags: python, mysql, database

I want to retrieve data from mysql using python. For that I use mySQLdb module. while compiling I got error

```
import MySQLdb
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

How can I solve this issue on a Windows machine?

Answer (score 1):

pip install your_file_path:/mysqlclient-1.3.13-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl,
The download address for this package is https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider formatting your answer properly, and perhaps suggests on why your solution would work.